# I am unable to populate the form with initial values from the state

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am unable to populate the form fields with the supplied initial values. Got 
    stuck.
    I am using "react": "^16.2.0" and redux-form": "7.4.0". Please help me on where I got stuck in the code. Even I tired hardcoded the initialValues but still no luck.

Can somebody please help me?

This is my code. Spent most of the time for this.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { SubmissionError } from 'redux-form'
import { addStore } from "../actions/storeActions.js";
import { loadStore } from "../actions/storeActions.js";
//import submit from './submit'
import './bundle.css';
const required = value => (value ? undefined : 'Required')
const phoneNumber = value =>
    value && !/^(0|[1-9][0-9]{9})$/i.test(value)
        ? 'Invalid phone number, must be 10 digits'
        : undefined

const number = value =>
    value && isNaN(Number(value)) ? 'Must be a number' : undefined
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, value, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
    <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} value={value} />
            {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </div>
    </div>
)
function throwError(msg) {
    throw new SubmissionError({
        _error: msg
    })
}

function submit(values, props) {
    console.log(values, props);
    let msg;
    if ((msg = required(values.storeName)) !== undefined) {
        throwError("Store name is required")
    } else if ((msg = required(values.address)) !== undefined) {
        throwError("Address is required")
    } else if ((msg = required(values.phone)) !== undefined) {
        throwError("Phone number is required")
    } else if ((msg = phoneNumber(values.phone)) !== undefined) {
        throwError(msg)
    } else {
        props.dispatch(addStore(values, props.router));
    }
    //})
}

let StoreForm = props => {
    const { error, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, } = props
    return (

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(values => { submit(values, props) })}>

            <Field
                name="storeName"
                component={renderField}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Store Name"
                label="Store Name"

            />

            <Field
                name="address"
                component={renderField}

                type="text"
                placeholder="Address"
                label="Address"
            />
            <Field
                name="description"
                component={renderField}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Description"
                label="Description"
            />
            <Field
                name="phone"
                component={renderField}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Phone"
                label="Phone"

            />

            {error && <strong>{error}</strong>}
            <div>
                <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
                    Log In
        </button>
                <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
                    Clear Values
        </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        initialValues: () => dispatch(loadStore())
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        initialValues: state.storeReducer.items

    }
};


StoreForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'initializeFromState' // a unique identifier for this form
})(StoreForm)


StoreForm = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: { storeName: "SURSH" },
    })
)(StoreForm)





export default StoreForm
```

Comment: You havent provided the component class and render!!!

Comment: Can you correct my code?

Answer (score 0):

you havn't pass value in your Field components

Comment: Even after passing value in Field component still not working

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by wrong usage of `value` in your `renderField` function.

As you can see in the [official props docs](https://redux-form.com/7.4.0/docs/api/field.md/#props), the `value` is part of the `input` property.

You have to refactor the function in the following way:

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
    <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
            {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```